# Shuffle batches fit_generator Keras line-by-line processing

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, bigdata, generator

I'm training a Deep Learning model on a 30M lines file (each line is a sample) using Python Keras' [`fit_generator()`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/), which implements batch training. Since samples are of very different sizes, I'm using bucketing for efficiency reasons, to avoid having sparse batches.

To do that, I sorted the file by increasing line size, and I wrote a generator that iterates through the lines and yields a batch every time `n_batch` lines have been processed:

```
def generate_batches_from_file():
while True:        
    doc_list = []
    with open(path_to_file) as docs: 
        for my_counter,doc in enumerate(docs):
            doc_list.append(doc)            
            if my_counter % batch_size == 0:
                doc_array = truncation_padding_other_stuff(doc_list)
                yield(doc_array)
```

This way, the samples in each batch have equal or very similar sizes and the tensor yielded is dense.

In Deep Learning though, best practice requires that the batches are not passed to the model in the same order every epoch (for regularization purposes).

**How can I shuffle the batches in my setting, since I'm generating them on the fly, and I'm tied to processing the large sorted input file line by line for bucketing?**

*Note that I don't want to shuffle the samples within each  batch, I want the **batches** be passed in a different order at each epoch.*

**EDIT: I ended up writing each batch to disk and having a generator that shuffles the list of paths before iterating over it.
Final code on GitHub here: https://github.com/Tixierae/deep_learning_NLP/blob/master/HAN/preprocessing.py**

Comment: Why not separate the big training file into 1 file per bucket, then just shuffle the lines in those files?

Comment: Interesting question. You could split your data in separate files and reshuffle the files at the start of each epoch. The tensorflow dataset api also provides the possibility to shuffle data that's held in a buffer: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle

Comment: yes, I think I'll write each batch to disk, and have a generator that shuffles the path list before iterating through it.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity suppose you have 1000 training samples (denoted by `n_samples`) and the batch size is set to 10. You have sorted the lines so the batches would be: `(docs[0],...,docs[9]), (docs[10],...,docs[19]),...,(docs[990],...,docs[999])`. Therefore, to generate batches in different order, you can easily store the starting index of each batch and then shuffle them at the start of each epoch:

```
import numpy as np

def generate_batches_from_file():
    indices = np.arange(0, n_samples, batch_size) 
    while True:
        # shuffle the indices each time to generate batches in different order
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
        with open(path_to_file) as docs:
            for idx in indices:
                doc_array = truncation_padding_other_stuff(docs[idx:idx+batch_size])
                yield(doc_array)
```

Comment: your solution assumes the input file can be loaded to RAM, which I thought I had made clear is not possible in my case (30M lines, line by line processing). Instead of idxs, I could use byte offset positions with tell and seek, but it doesn't work for me as I'm actually jointly processing two files: documents and labels. So there is a line-by-line correspondence, but obviously not byte to byte. I think the best solution for me is to write each batch to disk and just read the files in different orders at the start of every epoch, as was suggested in the comments.

Comment: @Antoine Just store your data in a h5py file and then adapt the above solution and it would work. I think storing them as batches is pointless and extremely inefficient (suppose you want to change the batch-size, etc.).

Comment: @Antoine I take my word back that storing batches on disk is extremely inefficient.    I should make a comparison to another solution to say that. I don't know about the specifics of your data (i.e. maximum and minimum number of elements in a line, the preprocessing of batches, etc.) to be able to compare it with a solution based on h5py.